# rsync & rdiff backup combination giving erros

Tags: rsync, rdiff-backup

On the server I'm making every day a backup with rdiff-backup like:
    rdiff-backup  /home/ /backup/home

Then every week I want to make a rsync backup offside with sshfs like:

```
rsync -avz /home/server/backup/home /backup/server-home/
```

This is giving me the following errors:

```
Fatal Error: Previous backup to /backup/server-home/. seems to have failed.
Rerun rdiff-backup with --check-destination-dir option to revert directory to state    before unsuccessful session.
```

Does anybody have a good solution to deal with this errors/situation?

*2x edit for typo's

Comment: Can you confirm the error "Previous backup..." is actually from *rdiff-backup*, not *rsync*?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "--delete" option: this causes rsync to delete files from the destination directory if they no longer exist in the source. Also, it's possible that "-H" is required (to preserve hard links)